# $('body').layout is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-layout

I'm using the [jQuery UI Layout plugin](http://layout.jquery-dev.net/) and I keep getting this error in Firebug: `$('body').layout is not a function`. I also get the same error in IE8 and below.

Obviously, it's being caused by the line where I initiate the layout UI in my scripts file:

```
$('body').layout({ *options here* });
```

Is there a way to prevent this error from showing? I'm pretty sure I need the BODY selector for this particular plugin to run.

** ***SOLUTION*** **

As the helpful answers say below, I had this line: `$('body').layout({ *options here* });` BEFORE I included my jQuery and jQuery UI Layout Plugin files. Once I put the `body.layout` after those two inclusions, the error went away.

Comment: Make sure you are including the jQuery layout plugin script into your page and that you are only including one copy of jquery.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to either

1) have not included the plugin properly (script tag missing/typo in the url, included it before loading jquery itself, whatever else could go wrong)

or

2) calling `$("body").layout` too early - wrap it with `$(document).ready(function() { });`

it should be

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.layout.js"></script>

...

<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function() {
      $("body").layout() // will work now
   });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you're including the lines:

```
<SCRIPT type="text/javascript" src="/path/to/jquery-latest.js"></SCRIPT>
<SCRIPT type="text/javascript" src="/path/to/jquery.layout-latest.js"></SCRIPT>
```

Prior to the code you placed in your question. Otherwise, layout will have been undefined before use.

Comment: This is also a very helpful answer! +1